# Bearer error="invalid_token"

Tags: asp.net-core

У меня на сервере создается JWT токен, который я отправляю на клиент при успешной аутентификации. Но в headers запроса, когда я хочу вытащить из jwt данные, сервер выдает ошибку 401, а так же в headers пишет ошибку:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас пойдет основной код, который за это отвечает:

Program.cs:

```
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
        {
            Description = "Standard Authorization header using the Bearer scheme (\"Bearer  {token}\")",
            In = ParameterLocation.Header,
            Name = "Authorization",
            Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
        });
    
        options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
    });
    
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8
                    .GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false
            };
        });
```

UserService.cs:

```
 public async Task<AuthResponseDto> Login(User request)
        {
            var user = await _context.UserJwt.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Phone == request.Phone);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return new AuthResponseDto { Message = "User not found." };
            }

            if (!VerifyPasswordHash(request.Password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
            {
                return new AuthResponseDto { Message = "Wrong Password." };
            }

            string token = CreateToken(user);
            var refreshToken = CreateRefreshToken();
            SetRefreshToken(refreshToken, user);

            return new AuthResponseDto
            {
                Success = true,
                Token = token,
                RefreshToken = refreshToken.Token,
                TokenExpires = refreshToken.Expires
            };
        }

        public async Task<UserJWT> RegisterUser(User request)
        {
            CreatePasswordHash(request.Password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt);

            var user = new UserJWT()
            {
                FIO = request.FIO,
                PasswordHash = passwordHash,
                PasswordSalt = passwordSalt,
                Address = request.Address,
                Phone = request.Phone,
                Id = request.Id,
                Email = request.Email
            };

            _context.UserJwt.Add(user);
            _context.Users.Add(request);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return user;
        }

        public async Task<AuthResponseDto> RefreshToken()
        {
            var refreshToken = _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Request.Cookies["refreshToken"];
            var user = await _context.UserJwt.FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.RefreshToken == refreshToken);
            if(user == null)
            {
                return new AuthResponseDto { Message = "Invalid Refresh Token" };
            }
            else if(user.TokenExpires < DateTime.Now)
            {
                return new AuthResponseDto { Message = "Token expired." };
            }

            string token = CreateToken(user);
            var newRefreshToken = CreateRefreshToken();
            SetRefreshToken(newRefreshToken, user);

            return new AuthResponseDto
            {
                Success = true,
                Token = token,
                RefreshToken = newRefreshToken.Token,
                TokenExpires = newRefreshToken.Expires
            };
        }

        private bool VerifyPasswordHash(string password, byte[] passwordHash, byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512(passwordSalt))
            {
                var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
                return computedHash.SequenceEqual(passwordHash);
            }
        }

        private void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA512())
            {
                passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
                passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            }
        }

        private string CreateToken(UserJWT user)
        {
            List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.PrimarySid, user.TokenId.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FIO),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, user.Phone),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.StreetAddress, user.Address),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email),
            };

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                _configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

            var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                signingCredentials: creds);

            var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);

            return jwt;
        }

        private RefreshToken CreateRefreshToken()
        {
            var refreshToken = new RefreshToken
            {
                Token = Convert.ToBase64String(RandomNumberGenerator.GetBytes(64)),
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7),
                Created = DateTime.Now
            };

            return refreshToken;
        }

        private async Task SetRefreshToken(RefreshToken refreshToken, UserJWT user)
        {
            var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
            {
                HttpOnly = true,
                Expires = refreshToken.Expires,
            };
            _httpContextAccessor?.HttpContext?.Response
                .Cookies.Append("refreshToken", refreshToken.Token, cookieOptions);

            user.RefreshToken = refreshToken.Token;
            user.TokenCreated = refreshToken.Created;
            user.TokenExpires = refreshToken.Expires;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        public string GetInfoJWT()
        {
       
            var result = string.Empty;
            if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext != null)
            {
                result = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

UserController:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserJWT>> RegisterUser(User request)
{
    var response = await _userService.RegisterUser(request);
    return Ok(response);
}

[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<ActionResult<UserJWT>> Login(User request)
{
    var response = await _userService.Login(request);
    if(response.Success)
        return Ok(response);

    return BadRequest(response.Message);
}

[HttpPost("refresh-token")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> RefreshToken()
{
    var response = await _userService.RefreshToken();
    if (response.Success)
        return Ok(response);

    return BadRequest(response.Message);
}

[HttpGet("getme"),Authorize]
public ActionResult<string> Aloha()
{
    var userName = _userService.GetInfoJWT();
    return Ok(userName);
}
```

Что может вызывать эту ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была шаблоне создания токена:

```
return new AuthResponseDto
            {
                Success = true,
                Token = token,
                RefreshToken = refreshToken.Token,
                TokenExpires = refreshToken.Expires
            };
```

Я не углядел за тем, что в токене была лишняя информация, которая рушила его структуру. Собственно, это и вызывало ошибку 401.